# ResKit iOS - Application crash when i receive HTTP Error Code in RKObjectManager postObject method

Tags: iphone, ios

i'm using RKObjectManager to make iOS RESTful requests to map responses to local objects. When i receive HTTP error codes like 400, RestKit sends data to RKObjectLoaderDelegate method:

```
- (void)objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader
```

but immediately afterwards the application crash without any reason.
The debugger doesn't give me any more information, where and why the application crashes.

To make the request

```
RKObjectManager * objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:SERVER_BASE_URL];

RKDynamicRouter* router = [[RKDynamicRouter new] autorelease];
objectManager.router = router;
objectManager.format = RKMappingFormatJSON;

[router routeClass:[RKTUser class] toResourcePath:@"sessions" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user delegate:self];
```

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated RestKit framework, and it start to work.